# VS2017 Cordova iOS Local Device Deploy

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using **Visual Studio 2017** on Win10 with the blank Cordova app project.
I am able to build and deploy to Android and iOS simulators fine.
I am able to build and deploy to iOS "Remote Device" just fine.

However, I am having a problem with iOS "Local Device".
It builds fine, but the problem occurs in Deploy.
Here is the error:

> File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\node_modules\vs-libimobile\lib\ideviceprovision.exe
>   could not be found.

After this failure, it deploys to iTunes. But, now this seems to require manually installing it, and iTunes always asks if I want to replace it each build. Plus, you can't actually run the VS TACO debugger this way. Obviously, this is not what is supposed to happen.

I have setup iOS Local Device Deploy on a Win7 PC with VS2015 and it works as expected. I'm just trying to migrate the tools to a new PC and get up and running with VS2017.

I'm a newbie with all of this, including npm and node.js. I've tried doing "npm install -g vs-libimobile", but it's not being installed where VS2017 seems to want it. I've also tried to copy/paste it there, but it's a read-only folder. This seems to be a bug with VS2017. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting something similar. `File node_modules\vs-libimobile\lib\ideviceprovision.exe could not be found.`  I have vs-limimobile installed globally and locally in the project node_modules.  I don't know where it's looking for it, but it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Magically, "Local Device" deployment just started working!!

Honestly, I don't know exactly what changed. My best guess is that I opened a .config file that caused VS2015 to open (instead of VS2017). Maybe just opening/closing VS2015 caused something to change in an environment variable or Registry setting?

What I noticed is that the "node_modules" folder containing "vs-libimobile" is now being created at the same folder level as the .sln file. I suspect that's important.

Hope this helps someone.